# Create thumbnail image for PDF in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

I have this code in a Smarty template that generates file links (which will be PDF format):

```
   {foreach from=$attachments_data item="file"}
        <p class="attachment__item">        
        {$file.description} ({$file.filename}, {$file.filesize|formatfilesize nofilter}) [<a class="attachment__a cm-no-ajax" href="{"attachments.getfile?attachment_id=`$file.attachment_id`"|fn_url}">{__("download")}</a>]
        </p>
    {/foreach}
```

I found in another question a method of using PHP to generate a preview image from a PDF.

```
<?php
$im = new imagick('file.pdf[0]');
$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $im;
?>
```

Is there a way I can convert this PHP to Smarty in order to work with my CS-Cart template file? or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Simply treat the PHP URL that is generating your image as you would the regular image URL you would use in the <img> tag.

Comment: @Scuzzy I don't think you understand the question. I need the Smarty equivalent of that PHP script.

Comment: No, I understand, but you wouldn't use "smarty" to return your binary image/jpeg content. You would either generate them in PHP and then write them to a folder for static reading, or serve them dynamically from a PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

My preference would be to cache these to a tempoary folder for static reading, however, you can do this on-demand with that portion of PHP you've provided quite easily

PLEASE IMPLEMENT BETTER FILE SYSTEM SECURITY

**pdf_to_image.php**

```
<?php

// you must create better file system security than this
$filename = 'directory_with_pdfs' . DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR . basename( $_GET['filename'] );
if( file_exists( $filename ) === true )
{
  $im = new imagick( $filename . '[0]' );
  $im->setImageFormat('jpg');
  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
  echo $im;
}
else
{
  http_response_code(404);
}
```

**Smarty Syntax**

```
{foreach from=$attachments_data item="file"}
  <img src="pdf_to_image.php?filename={$file.filename|urlencode}">
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the example. When I try this though, the img src remains pdf_to_image.php...

Comment: I can't help beyond this simple approach, what I recommend, is creating a publicly readable directory with write access, and creating your jpg thumbnails as your script is executing when they don't exist, then referencing those URL's via your smarty template.